# Get a 403 error when adding an image to the online registration page in event management

Tags: civievent

Using CiviCRM 4.6.6. on Drupal 7.56

Just moved this site to a new server following normal procedures.

When managing an event, I can add an image to the info and settings page, but when I try to add one to the Online Registration page, the registration page is returned incorrectly and I get a 403 error. The event ID is completely lost. This is intermittent. Sometimes the page saves the image.

Trying again on 4.7.22. Endless spinning triangle of death.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it's ModSecurity on the server interfering with things.