# 403 error message with photos

Tags: civievent

I am attempting to add a photo to an event we have and every time I try to upload the photo into the system I get a 403 error. Please let me know how I can fix this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: This link is old but might be the same problem? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19592/get-a-403-error-when-adding-an-image-to-the-online-registration-page-in-event-ma